# VS2010 Installer creation using CustomAction

Tags: windows-installer

I'm trying to create an installer with VS2010 that calls a utility that copies some files after the installer finishes it's installation.

What I've done is to create a utility program which accepts command line arguments for the destination (where the installer installed the package), and the source (the location of the installer files).

Next, in the installer project, I've added a CustomAction after the installer to call my utility (installed as part of the installation) with the arguments [TARGETDIR] [SourceDir].

The problem that I have is that [SourceDir] doesn't fill in with anything if the installer is located on a network drive!  If it's in a folder on any of my hard disks, or on a CD, or on a flash drive, the correct path is filled in.  If it's on a network drive (not mapped to a drive letter), the [SourceDir] that's passed to the utility is blank!

Any ideas on how to get the network location passed as the [SourceDir]?

[image: Installer's CustomAction settings for Copy utility]

[image: Install CustomAction to call Copy utility]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the OriginalDatabase property to see if that resolves any better.

However you're not likely to be successful unless you do your copy with a post-install program.

In an Everyone install (for all users) Visual Studio custom actions run with the system account. You say you're not mapped to a drive letter (and drive letters won't work because they belong to the interactive user, not the system account) but the system account has no network privileges and therefore attempts to resolve a network location fail, and your code wouldn't be able to do the copy anyway. That's why running a separate program with the interactive user's account would work, doing the copy the first time the user runs that app. Or the app design is such that the app knows the network location of the extra file and can access it directly. I'm not aware of any other solution in your situation.

Comment: Thanks Phil...I've more or less discovered the same thing :(  I replaced my copy utility with another that lets me navigate to the source of the files, and when the OpenFile dialog opens, none of the network locations were visable-Exactly what you said would happen.  I'm now working on a Cmd file that runs the installer, the installer builds a cmd file with the correct paths, and after the installer finishes, the first cmd file runs the second...I haven't finished debugging yet, but it's looking promising.